# can't access github via https after upgrade to Yosemite

Tags: macos, git, github, https

I can't access GitHub via https after upgrade my Mac to Yosemite.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/': SSL: can't load CA certificate file
```

Actually,it's brew update,most of brew operations are via https when requesting github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Using git version 2.1.2 (on Yosemite) I'm able to download the repo just fine:

```
git clone https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask.git/
Cloning into 'flask'...
remote: Counting objects: 10113, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 10113 (delta 2), reused 5 (delta 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (10113/10113), 4.66 MiB | 1.52 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6112/6112), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Comment: @pigletfly Then, like VonC suggested, you should check for bad or expired certificates in your keychain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching to ssh:

```
 git clone git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask.git
```

With https, you need to have your CAs (Certificate Authorities) in order ([as in this question](https://superuser.com/q/721778/141)).

Comment: yeah,ssh is ok.Actually,it's brew update,most of brew operations are  via https when requesting github repo.

Comment: @pigletfly at least, for cloning, ssh is enough.

Comment: I followed your link,it doesn't work.The expired certificate is still there.